# Automatically domain and range filling in Protégé 4.3

Tags: protege, protege4

I'm following the instructions of **A Practical Guide to Building OWL Ontologies Using Protégé 4 - Edition 1.3**, and it says that when the domain of a property is filled, the range of its inverse property should automatically be filled by Protégé. However, it's not true anymore in **Protégé 4.3**.

Does someone know if there is a missing step here in this new version?

Comment: If I access Reasoner > Configure..., and check Domains and Ranges options in Displayed Object Property Inferences, on Reasoner tab, the reasoner fills the domain and range of the inverse properties. But is it needed, really?

Comment: When I run the reasoner, it find true domain and ranges for inverse properties. but when I export inferred axioms as ontology, inferences of range and domain don't appear in result! Do you can save inferred ranges and domains? if you can, how?!